# clone select element and wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I clone multiple select elements in the following manner. This work perfectly:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36308/

```
// get all items of specific class
var $selectedClassDiv = $('.to-clone');

// find select eles and clone into div
$('#cloned-list').html($selectedClassDiv.find('select').clone());

// loop through cloned select eles to set the correct selected option
$selectedClassDiv.find("select").each(function(i) {
  var select = this;
  $('#cloned-list').find("select").eq(i).val($(select).val());
});
```

The problem I have is that I would like to wrap these select items in a div that has a custom class. I've tried multiple methods to no avail, my latest attempts below.

---

#### Has no effect

```
$('#cloned-list').html($selectedClassDiv.find('select').clone().wrap('<div class="customClass"></div>'));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36309/

#### Causes error

```
$('#cloned-list').html($selectedClassDiv.find('select').clone().parent().wrap('<div class="customClass"></div>'));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36310/

I am interested in a solution that wraps a div around the select items. Cloning the parent div and adding a class isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it within your current loop:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36311/

```
$selectedClassDiv.find("select").each(function(i) {
  var select = this;
  $('#cloned-list').find("select").eq(i).val($(select).val()).wrap('<div class="customClass"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way doing this task in less code, or have I got it at it's most optimised state?